# Setting the text in EditText dynamically on a button click

Tags: android

I have two EditTexts that have two different values and a button, on click of that button, result of the multiplication should be displayed in the third Edit Text.

Code Written for the function on the button click:

```
public void Multiply (View view)
{
String str1 = ed1.getText().toString();
        String str2 = ed2.getText().toString();

        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(str1);
        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(str2);

        int prod = num1*num2;

        //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Product is"+(num1*num2),Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();

        ed3.setText(prod);

}
```

Comment: You set int value, but Android expext integer == Resource id. So you need to convert prod to String. ed3.setText(String.valueOf(prod));

Answer (score 2):

Mistake:

```
 ed3.setText(prod);
```

Try:

```
ed3.setText(String.valueOf(prod));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
ed3.setText(String.valueOf(prod));
```

or

```
ed3.setText(""+prod);
```

Answer (score 0):

EditText won't allow integer to go directly in `setText`. So convert it into string before setting it

Try this

`ed3.setText(String.valueOf(prod));`

Comment: It is displaying some syntax error, asking to insert ')' after the expression.

Comment: Hmm.. Wired have you tried this one `ed3.setText(String.valueOf(prod));`

Comment: I have used exactly the same expression, but it is displaying this error.

Comment: I'm sharing the whole code with you. Kindly cross-check, I didnt find any braces left unopened.


public void Multiply(View view)
    {
     String str1 = ed1.getText().toString();
     String str2 = ed2.getText().toString();
     
     int num1 = Integer.parseInt(str1);
     int num2 = Integer.parseInt(str2);
     
     int product = num1*num2;
     
      ed3.setText(String.valueOf(product));
    
    }

Comment: Vino : I'm waiting for your reply, as I'm new here, so don't know much about it, respond ASAP.

Comment: No problem with the code its correct. the problem should be some where restart the eclipse. it may help

Answer (score 0):

you can simple add `ed3.setText(""+prod);` as edittext directly not accept the integer value.